# Using Fluent NHibernate, how to map one entity to differently named tables?

Tags: nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

To be clear, I am looking to map one entire object and all its properties to different copies of basically the same table.  My searches show me how to split an object's properties across multiple tables, but that is not what I am trying to accomplish.

Here is my object model (stripped down):

```
class Customer 
{
   public Guid CustomerGuid { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
   public Guid AddressGuid { get; set; }
   public string Line1 { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
}

class Application
{
   public Guid ApplicationGuid { get; set; }
   public Address Address { get; set; }
   public DateTime SubmittedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I need the Address to act sort like a component, but be saved into two separate tables:  CustomerAddress and ApplicationAddress, as such:

```
table Customer
(
   CustomerGuid
   Name
)

table Application
(
   ApplicationGuid
   SubmittedDate
)

table CustomerAddress
(
   CustomerGuid
   Line1
   State
)

table ApplicationAddress
(
   ApplicationGuid
   Line1
   State
)
```

I know I can accomplish one of the mappings using as one-to-one (HasOne) for say Customer to CustomerAddress, but then how can I do the same thing with Application to ApplicationAddress?

Comment: If the two addresses go into two different tables in the database, then I would not try to force the objects to user one mapping class. That would be bad design. A mapping class describes how "a table" in database looks like so using one mapping class to describe two tables would be wrong. You can modify your database schema to have one address table and then use one mapping class.

Comment: The database schema is fixed; a legacy design that I cannot control.  I am trying to replace an existing proprietary persistence framework in our application with NHibernate.  It sounds like that might not be possible.

Comment: If the database has two address table, I would not try to use one address mapping class.

Answer (score 1):

for customer and analog for Application

```
class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, "CustomerGuid").GeneratedBy.GuidComb();

        Map(x => x.Name);
        Join("CustomerAddress", join =>
        {
            join.KeyColumn("CustomerGuid");
            join.Component(x => x.Address, c =>
            {
                c.Map(x => x.Line1);
                c.Map(x => x.State);
            });
        });
    }
}
```